# jquery click event calls 2 times

Tags: jquery, html

In my function, while i add the click event to object, that, calling two times. i found no. of solution in the form but nothing helped.

can any one help me to sort this out?

my code :

```
function accordionOptions(AccordionBox, AccordionSec) {
    var accordionBox = AccordionBox,
        accordionSec = AccordionSec;

    $.each(accordionSec, function (i, values) {
        $('h3', values).each(function () {
            $(this).unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings('.expand-area').slideToggle().end().parent().siblings().children('h3').removeClass('selected').siblings('.expand-area').slideUp();

                var subSec = $(this).parent().children().find('.subSec');

                $(subSec).click(function () {
                    console.log(this.tagName); // i am getting 2 times...why?
                })

            });
        })
    })

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var accordionBox = $('#Accordion'),
        accordionSec = {
            accorIndice: $('#sec1', '#Accordion'),
            accorGeography: $('#sec2', '#Accordion'),
            accorAllIndia: $('#sec3', '#Accordion')
        }
    accordionOptions(accordionBox, accordionSec);
});
```

it is very long HTML, so i unabale to place here. sorry

some part of HTML:

```
<ul class='subSec'>
    <li>
        <h4>1. Select a key index</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="CCI" name="cci" checked>Consumer Confidence Index</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="HW" name="cci">Housewives Index</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class='subSec'>
    <li>
        <h4>2. Select your sub-indices (optional)</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="CSI" name="subIndices">Consumer Spending Index</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="EI" name="subIndices">Employment Index</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="Ii" name="subIndices">Inflation Index</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="OI" name="subIndices">Onion Index</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="CI" name="subIndices">Corruption Index</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Determine how you $.each() runs

Comment: @3gwebtrain that normal because you add `click of class` inside `click` of `h3`so you have to click twice to show `log`

Comment: can you explain me.? understand. how to avoid then?

Answer (score 0):

How about `return false;` at end of click event function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an event bubbling issue, though it is tempting to think it might be.

The problem seems to be that `var subSec = $(this).parent().children().find('.subSec');` finds the same `.subSec` more than once and thus attaches its click handler more than once.

As far as I can tell, you should be able to remove the `$.each(accordionSec,function(i,values){...});` wrapper and attach click functionality to your `h3` elements with:

```
$('h3', context).each(function(){
    ...
});
```

I'm not sure of the `context` without seeing more of the HTML but you should be able to work that out. (Try '#' + the id of the accordian's outer wrapper).

EDIT:

Oh yes, you also need to liberate `$(subSec).click(function () {...));` from inside the outer click handler, otherwise subSecs' click functionality will be added over and over every time the outer click event occurs.

Comment: Nope, in some cases, i have more than 2 instance of the '.subSec', but it's only calling 2 times.

Comment: I don't think it's determined by the number of 'subSecs' but the number of 'accordionSecs'.